How to solve dice problem using infinite series and combinations?
I came across an interesting dice problem that goes like this:
James will roll a fair, six-sided die until he gets a 4. What is the expected value of the highest number he rolls through this process?
There is a really nice way to solve it by using intuitive counting of the subsets for the probability space of $X$, but I wanted to solve it using infinite series.
To start off, I have done the following:

$X$ = Highest number rolled before rolling a 4 = $\{4,5,6\}$

$E[X] = 4\cdot \mathbb{P}(X=4) + 5\cdot \mathbb{P}(X=5) + 6\cdot \mathbb{P}(X=6)$


It is easy to see that $\mathbb{P}(X=4) = 1/3$ . We can use infinite series to get $\mathbb{P}(X=5)$; If we imagine the scenario where we keep rolling 5's until we roll a 4 we can determine the probability to be
$$
\mathbb{P}(X=5) = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^i = \frac{1}{6}.
$$
However I am struggling to determine how to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X=6)$. I thought about it the following way:

if we have to roll $i$ times before getting a 4, then we have to roll a 6 potentially $j$ out of those $i$ times, with $j<i$. I have thought of the following sum but would have no idea how to calculate it (and not sure if it's the correct reasoning)

$$\mathbb{P}(X=6) = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{j=1}^i \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^i \cdot C(i,j)$$
Would anyone have any ideas? Thanks so much!

If the final $4$ is in the maximum calculation then your definition of $X$ might use a better word than "before".

The paths might be quite complicated, so rather than long series I'd suggest using states.  There are only $3$ active states, characterized by the highest element you've seen.  The start state, you might as well call "$4$" since you know $4$ is the least possible answer.  And once you see a $6$ you can stop, as that is obviously the answer.

But, honestly, it's enough to remark that the six sequences ${456, 465, 546, 564, 645, 654}$ are equally likely, none of the other throws matter, so the answer is $4\times \frac 13+5\times \frac 16+6\times \frac 13=\frac {31}6$.

@lulu: It should be $6\times \frac12$ in your comment.

Thanks guys! I was overcomplicating my reasoning, the states approach is the best way to go

You say "It is easy to see that $\mathbb{P}(X=4) = \frac13$" and then use an infinite sum to find $\mathbb{P}(X=5) = \frac16$.  That leaves $\mathbb{P}(X=6)=1-\frac13-\frac16=\frac12$, and so $\mathbb E[X]=\frac{31}{6}$.
Another way of finding the same probabilities is to imagine continuing to roll until you have seen all three.  The order in which they first appear is equally likely for each of the $3!=6$ permutations. So:

$(4,5,6)$ and $(4,6,5)$ give $X=4$ with probability $\frac26$
$(5,4,6)$ gives $X=5$ with probability $\frac16$
$(6,4,5)$ and $(6,5,4)$ and $(5,6,4)$ give $X=6$ with probability $\frac36$

Yet another way to say $\mathbb{P}(X=6)=\frac12$ is to say that $4$ and $6$  are equally likely to first appear before the other, and when $6$ appears before $4$ then $X=6$.

Thanks so much ! I really like the reasoning for $\mathbb{P}(X=6) = 1/2$ using the fact that 4 and 6 are both equally likely to appear before the other.

To illustrate the use of infinite series, I have slightly altered the problem.  You are going to throw a fair die, until the first $~4~$ is thrown.  Ignoring the die throw of $~4,~$ what is the expected value of the highest number thrown, on all of the other die throws.
Clarification:
If the very first die throw is a $~4,~$ this will be interpreted as the highest other number thrown being a $~0.~$
Let $~S~$ denote the set $~\{0,1,2,3,5,6\}.$
For $~n \in S,~$ let $~f(n)~$ denote the probability that prior to the first die throw of $~4,~$ the largest die throw was $~\leq n.~$
Clarification:
$f(0)~$ represents the probability that the very first die throw was $~4,$ and $~f(6) = 1.$
Let

$g(6) = f(6) - f(5).$

$g(5) = f(5) - f(3).$

$g(3) = f(3) - f(2).$

$g(2) = f(2) - f(1).$

$g(1) = f(1) - f(0).$

$g(0) = f(0) = \dfrac{1}{6}.$


Then, the expected value of the highest number thrown before the first $~4,~$ is
$$\sum_{n \in S} \left[ ~n \times g(n) ~\right]. \tag1 $$
So, the problem is reduced to deriving a closed form formula, for $~f(n),~$ deriving a closed form formula for $~g(n),~$ performing the computation in (1) above, and then (if feasible) simplifying the result.

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~f(5)}$
In order for the largest number thrown, other than $~4~$ to be no larger than $~5,~$ you need there to exist some $~m \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}},~$ such that :

the first $~m~$ die throws, were all elements in $~S\setminus\{0\}.$

none of the first $~m~$ die throws were $~> 5.$

the die throw $~(m+1)~$ was a $~4.$


So,
$$f(5) = \frac{1}{6} \times \sum_{m=0}^\infty \left[ ~\frac{4}{6} ~\right]^m$$
$$= \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{1 - \frac{4}{6}} = \frac{1/6}{2/6} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~f(n) ~: ~n \in \{1,2,3\}}$
Similar to the analysis in the previous section,
$$f(n) = \frac{1}{6} \times \sum_{m=0}^\infty \left[ ~\frac{n}{6} ~\right]^m$$
$$= \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{1 - \frac{n}{6}} = \frac{1/6}{[6 - n]/6} = \frac{1}{6 - n}.$$

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~g(n)}$

$~g(6) = 1 - \dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2}.$ 
Intuition here is that the very first $~6~$ and the very first $~4~$ might occur in either order.

$~g(5) = \dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{1}{3} = \dfrac{1}{6}.$

Intuition here is that the very first $~6,~$ the very first $~5,~$ and the very first $~4~$ must specifically be ordered $~5 - 4 - 6.$

$~g(3) = \dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{1}{4} = \dfrac{1}{12}.$

Intuition here is that the very first $~6,~$ the very first $~5,~$ the very first $~3,~$ and the very first $~4~$ must specifically be ordered either $~3 - 4 - 6 - 5, ~$ or $~3 - 4 - 5 - 6.$

$~g(2) = \dfrac{1}{4} - \dfrac{1}{5} = \dfrac{1}{20}.$

$~g(1) = \dfrac{1}{5} - \dfrac{1}{6} = \dfrac{1}{30}.$

$~g(0) = f(0) = \dfrac{1}{6}.$


So, the expected value is
$$\left[ ~0 \times \frac{1}{6} \right] + 
\left[ ~1 \times \frac{1}{30} \right] + 
\left[ ~2 \times \frac{1}{20} \right] \\
+ 
\left[ ~3 \times \frac{1}{12} \right] + 
\left[ ~5 \times \frac{1}{6} \right] + 
\left[ ~6 \times \frac{1}{2} \right] \\
= \frac{253}{60}.$$
